Kernel replaced boot.img won't boot
i compiled a kernel for my phone which is the Samsumg Galaxy A03, running Android 13 on the UNISOC T606 chipset. But i cannot get the kernel to boot. I flashed the kernel(boot.img) with odin on Windows. The machine i use is the Hp elitebook 8470p, dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.
As said in the instruction provided with the kernel, i need gcc 4.9 and clang r383902 to compile. The environment for compiling is Ubuntu 22.04. I need testing first so the only thing i changed in the config is the local version( I loaded the config from /proc/config.gz on the phone). After compiled the output files are: a "dts" folder, image.gz, image; i used image as kernel. To make a boot.img, i tried 3 tools: mkbootimg , mkboot , Imgutil . The stock boot.img size is 64mb, after replace/repack it with the new kernel the new boot.img size is 24mb. And none of them boot, the phone bootlooping, it get to the splash screen and fade away. For more information, this phone support UART communication so i can see the boot console:
[    0.000000] [0:        swapper:    0] [    T0] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] [0:        swapper:    0] [    T0] Linux version 4.14.199 (ubuntu@ubuntu-HP-EliteBook-8470p) (Android (6443078 based on r383902) clang version 11.0.1 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project b397f81060ce6d701042b782172ed13bee898b79), LLD 11.0.1 (/buildbot/tmp/tmp6_m7QH b397f81060ce6d701042b782172ed13bee898b79)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 11 10:47:37 +07 2024
[    0.000000] [0:        swapper:    0] [    T0] Boot CPU: AArch64 Processor [412fd050]
[    0.000000] [0:        swapper:    0] [    T0] Machine model: Spreadtrum UMS9230 1H10 SoC
[    0.000000] [0:        swapper:    0] [    T0] earlycon: sprd_serial0 at MMIO 0x00000000200b0000 (options '115200n8')
[    0.000000] [0:        swapper:    0] [    T0] bootconsole [sprd_serial0] enabled
[    0.032000] [0:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: [sysdump_info_init]vmcore info init end!
[    0.104000] [0:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: log_buf added successfully in minidump section:paddr_start=17ba00000,paddr_end=17bc00000
[    0.108000] [0:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: per_cpu added successfully in minidump section:paddr_start=17fdd9000,paddr_end=17ff09000
[    0.112000] [0:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: etb_data added successfully in minidump section:paddr_start=0,paddr_end=0
[    0.116000] [0:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: vmcoreinfo added successfully in minidump section:paddr_start=17aa8f000,paddr_end=17aa91000
[    0.356000] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sec_debug:__sec_debug_dt_addr_init() restart_reason addr : 0x        (ptrval)(0x81b3d7e0)
[    0.368000] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sec_debug:__sec_debug_dt_addr_init() upload_cause addr : 0x        (ptrval)(0x81b457e4)
[    0.380000] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sec_debug:__sec_debug_dt_addr_init()  sprd imem dt set!!!
[    0.388000] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sec_debug:sec_debug_set_upload_cause() cafebabe
[    0.656034] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: task_stats added successfully in minidump section:paddr_start=177800000,paddr_end=17785620e
[    0.669616] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: runqueue added successfully in minidump section:paddr_start=1787e4000,paddr_end=1787e7e80
[    0.683056] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: stack_regs added successfully in minidump section:paddr_start=177880000,paddr_end=177896800
[    0.973363] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd_wdh: func_addr = 0xffffff80080840f4, pgd = 0x81b1c000
[    1.240908] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: ylog_buf added successfully in minidump section:paddr_start=176c00000,paddr_end=176d00000
[    1.254291] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: kernel_pt added successfully in minidump section:paddr_start=81b1c000,paddr_end=81b1e000
[    1.267606] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: nhang added successfully in minidump section:paddr_start=818b06a0,paddr_end=819b06a0
[    1.280688] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] sprd-sysdump: scproc added successfully in minidump section:paddr_start=62010000,paddr_end=6205dfff
[    1.473967] [6:      swapper/0:    1] [    T1] run init
[   76.173004] [6:    tsupplicant:  408] [  T408] vds_queue_txbuf not notify.
[   82.095479] [6:           init:    1] [    T1] sysrq: Kill All Tasks
[   82.555068] [0:           init:    1] [    T1] reboot: Restarting system with command 'bootchecker'

The only different from booting normally is it reboot when booting with 'bootchecker'.
